# How to only retrieve body field value using GetItemById?

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-item, getlist

I am making application page that add, edit, delete the list items.

Now I want to make Edit page, and I retrieved the Title and Body value.

But in body value, it returned like this.

```
<div class="ExternalClassD0DCC2B7E533459DA80922D67FE8A7A4"><p>Test 2​</p></div>
```

I don`t want to see div tag. How can I do that?

My code is below.

```
private void DisplaySelectedListItem()
{
    string siteUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;

    int id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

    using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(siteUrl))
    {
       using (SPWeb web = spSite.OpenWeb())
       {
          SPList list = web.GetListFromUrl("Lists/List/AllItems.aspx");
          SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(id);
          txtTitle.Text = item["Title"].ToString();
          txtBody.Text = item["Body"].ToString();
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I am a bit unsure about C# but there is something called FieldValuesAsText and if you Google it you can find some documentation. That is a collection of all the fields as keys and their values are plaintext values. It might contain the non-html version of your rich text field contents. Worth giving it a try I guess. :)

Comment: If you use a RichTextField for the body you should keep that functionality by using a richtextcontrol too. If you dont wan't the user to be able to input html you just have to edit the field settings and change it to plain text.

Comment: Thank you Alex Pedersen and Mx. Your comments are helpful to solve my problem! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code if you want to keep using the body as rich text field:

```
private void DisplaySelectedListItem()
{
    string siteUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;

    int id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

    using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(siteUrl))
    {
       using (SPWeb web = spSite.OpenWeb())
       {
          SPList list = web.GetListFromUrl("Lists/List/AllItems.aspx");
          SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(id);
          txtTitle.Text = item["Title"].ToString();
          SPFieldMultiLineText field = (SPFieldMultiLineText)item.Fields["Body"]; 
          txtBody.Text = field.GetFieldValueAsText(item["Body"]);         
        }
     }
}
```

Reference - [SPField.GetFieldValueAsText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.getfieldvalueastext(v=office.15).aspx)

Or as using SPUtility as below:

```
private void DisplaySelectedListItem()
{
    string siteUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;

    int id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

    using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(siteUrl))
    {
       using (SPWeb web = spSite.OpenWeb())
       {
          SPList list = web.GetListFromUrl("Lists/List/AllItems.aspx");
          SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(id);
          txtTitle.Text = item["Title"].ToString();
          string bodyValue = item["Body"].ToString();
          txtBody.Text = SPHttpUtility.ConvertSimpleHtmlToText(bodyValue, bodyValue.Length);       

        }
     }
}
```

For the above code, you need to add  `Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities` reference.

Reference - [SPHttpUtility.ConvertSimpleHtmlToText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sphttputility.convertsimplehtmltotext.aspx)

Else

In your list, make sure that the Multiple lines of text column setting is set to `plain text`

- Go to list setting
- click on the column name.
- Beside `Additional Column Settings`, Check `Plain text`

[image]

This will remove the rich text and automatically it becomes plain text. If you do this, no code change will be required.

Comment: Thank you Gautam Sheth! It works perfectly. And also your column setting tip is really helpful!!! :)